# Xamarin.Forms UWP missing references

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

When I create a new project in Xamarin.Forms I get a lot of errors in the UWP part of the project.
It looks like I miss all the referencs in UWP?

I installed Xamarin trough Visual Studios modify

Below is a screenshot of my Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: Did you restore Nuget packages for the UWP project?

Comment: Yep, and it did not make any difference

Comment: I had a similar problem. I updated to the latest Nuget package and now the missing Xamarin.Forms reference is available in the UWP project.

Answer (score 0):

I also started to work with Xamarin about two weeks ago and came across many problems and one was just like yours. If you dont have Xamarin studio go and download it. Just do it.

Intellisense breaks really often and you get 200 errors that are dump(or not).

To get rid of the errors there are many ways.

Sometimes you just have to wait.

Open the xaml pages and save them.

Clean - rebuild the project it should run(at third try). If it doesnt you have to open Xamarin studio and built it from there.

If your project is new, just delete it and create a new one.

If you have MVC 5 or Core 1 Installed you will have to remove them(if that doesnt help do a PC Reset like a format).

If it says something for .zip files, find them keep a backup and delete them. Xamarin will re-download on Build.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem here using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.  Unload the UWP and everything works.

Tried in Xamarin Studio Professional and the following error: -
Could not load project 'blah\blah.UWP\blah.UWP.csproj' with unknown item type '{A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A}'

The following link has some helpful points and mentions "UWP is available in Xamarin.Forms 2.1 and later"

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/

The default setup when creating a new project in VS 2015 Up2 is to use Xamarin Forms v2.0.0.6482, however when I try to update to v2.1.0.6529 I get nuget errors

Checking my output when trying to update to 2.1 using nuget i got the following: -

The content at 'https://{myteamcityserver}/guestAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform'' is not valid XML.
  Root element is missing.

So I turned of my local Package Source in Tools | NuGet Package Manager | Package Manager Settings | Package Sources

And woo hoo it all worked for me.

Regards
Peter